# Find limit of sequence, complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to calculate limit of this sequence: $$\left\{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\exp\left(\frac{i\pi}{n}\right)\right\}$$ My problem is that I can't extract real and imaginary parts. I think something has to do with $$\exp\left(\frac{i\pi}{n}\right)$$. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excuse the curtness $$1 \cdot e^{0}=1$$
so your sequence is convergent.

Comment: OK, but how Real part of function looks like?

Comment: @atomoutside Are you familiar with Euler's formula. If you are, evaluate the limit after substitution. If not its arguably the most beautiful formula in all of mathematics, and you should set aside time to study it.

Comment: So, by using Euler's formula I should get: $$\exp\left(\frac{i\pi}{n}\right)=\cos\frac{\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{n}$$, right?

Comment: @atomoutside correct, now just take the limit. You can also analyze the real and imaginary parts separately.

Comment: @Zach466920: doesn't $1\cdot e^0=1$ show that the limit exists, and is $1$?

Comment: @atomoutside: correct. As $n\to\infty$, to what do the real and imaginary parts tend?

Comment: @robjohn that was the point. I get what you're saying, sorry I was thinking of series convergence, but this is a sequence.

Comment: @Zach466920 real part limit is $1$ ($\lim \cos\frac{\pi}{n}=1$) and imaginary is $0$ ($\lim \sin\frac{\pi}{n}=0$, thus whole sequence converges to $1$, right?

Comment: @atomoutside Yes, in addition you should know what this sequence looks like. It comes in from infinity and then circles around and closes in on the point 1. Why does it spiral? From the real plane the equation is cosine periodic, and from the complex plane the equation is sine periodic, this makes a circle. The (1+1/n) factor starts out at infinity and then decreases to one.

Comment: @Zach466920 Thank you for your time and explanations. They helped me out big time :)

Comment: @atomoutside Your welcome